# What test to use to prove significance of deviation from correlation

Tags: correlation, outliers

I have two dependent variables (A and B) and one independent variable (C) for a group of individuals N.

In the correlation of A with C, there seems to be a group of outliers from the main line of the correlation.

This same group does follow the main line of the correlation in the correlation of B with C.

What statistical test should I use to prove this? I attached a figure to make clear what i am suggesting.[image]

Comment: Regardless of which test to use, statistical tests are invalid for testing hypotheses that have been built on the same data on which they are tested. So no test will in a valid way tell you that this is significant on the same data, and you will need to collect new independent data to test this. (Why would it not be enough to just show the graphs and say that it looks like this is going on, without any significance statement?)

Comment: In the left figure, it looks like you have the correlation wrong.  And I don't see any outliers.